# How do I embed a node creation form inside a view

Tags: 7, views, forms

I have a View with some fields and a couple of link items.

What I want to do is when I click on the link items, a node creation form associated with link should appear inside the view (the AJAX way).

The solution that I can think of is to embed the forms inside the view, but have no idea how to do that?

What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: For drupal 6 https://drupal.org/project/views_embed_form

Comment: @Bala: i am using Drupal 7 :(

Comment: check this http://kahthong.com/2012/01/embed-drupal-node-form-anywhere : with the help of views php module, you can add this line in php field " print drupal_render(node_add('NODE_TYPE')); "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope this will help you,

In Drupal 7 you can achieve by the following steps

- You can embed a **node creation form** inside a VIEW

  - Either in **VIEW Header** or you can created a **new VIEW and attach it to your VIEW**
- For this example I am embedding inside **Views Header**. Embedding inside **Views Header** will be the better options. Click to **Add Views Header**

  [image]
- Select Global: Text area

  [image]
- Add the PHP code and don't forget to change the **Text Format to PHP**

  [image]
- PHP code

  `<?php 
      module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
      $node_form = node_add('node_type');
      print drupal_render($node_form);
  ?>`

Note :

- Don't forget to replace **node_type** in the PHP code.
- Use **hook_form_alter** for node form redirection, as after the node creation the form will redirect to node detail page. If you want to redirect to your page then use `$form_state['redirect'] = 'mycustompage';` [reference](https://drupal.org/node/1074616#comment-4218548)
- Enable **PHP Filter** module using **admin/modules**

[image]

- Set the **Permissions** for this module by enabling "Administrator" for **Execute PHP Code** as follows:

[image]

If any one has better solution, please share it.

Comment: Would you please expand on "Use hook_form_alter for node form redirection"??

Comment: Also, if you could include that users have to enable the "PHP Filter" module, and select "Administrator" under the permissions for "Execute PHP code".

Thank you for your solution!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions I appreciate that. I missed out few comments. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Your welcome enjoy :)

Comment: This solution will render without passing certain routines and also implements a security issue. For example the simplify module won't work to remove elements from the form and you are not able to "build" forms from this content type the "views" fields way. You rather simply implement the node form "as is" from core, which is in most cases useless, since this form is too cluttered to get implemented in a block (sidebar etc...). Adding php code from the admin UI should be avoided on bigger projects with security concerns.

Comment: @inizio I am new to drupal so were do I put this code. I have tried it in hook_node_view in this hook I have add the $output like this $node->content['article'] = $output; but nothing happen. So after render how to attach it to the node view?

Comment: @JennyMccarthy No need to use `hook_node_view`. `hook_node_view` act on a node that is being assembled before rendering. Install [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) module and enable **PHP filter** (default) module. Go to your VIEWS and try to add new FIELD. You can see `Global: PHP` field. Inside this you can add  OR inside VIEWS Header.

Comment: @inizio Thanks for your reply. I want to attach the rendered node form in a node view(which we can see after adding a content in a content type) not in the view created by using the views module. Is there any way to attach this to the node view. I think the above php code will work but I don't know where to put this code? or which hook I have to use?

Comment: Just create a new **custom block** either using `admin/structure/block/add` OR [programmatically](http://rylyn.org/article/drupal7-create-block-programmatically)  and the add the above code and enable it as per your requirement.

Comment: @inizio Can you answer this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497392/attach-or-embed-node-add-form-with-a-view)

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy to play with some custom code, a similar question was asked on StackOverflow, and there were some pretty extensive solutions to embed forms within a view. All you would have to do is use the form_id of the node creation form specific to your type, and place it within one of the solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344754/drupal-7-how-to-display-node-add-sometype-form-on-another-page) within your site.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Inline Entity Form](https://drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) for this; the Commerce Kickstart employs this as part of the recipe for managing products and product variations. I'm sure there's more to it than I can recall right now, but if this looks promising I'll circle back and improve this answer (or, perhaps others will help improve this answer).

A potential alternative (or complimentary?) module might be [Entity Views Attach](https://drupal.org/project/eva), which, I believe is also employed in commerce kickstart.

Comment: Not sure if this emphases the wanted approach from the OT/OP. IEF and EVA are more targeted for survey forms approaches than for publishing content forms.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment the Views Headers solution posted by inizio, I haven't enough reputation.

Well I want to post that you can solve the form redirection after submission with [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules), and you don't have to create a custom module the hook_form_alter.

- Create a Rule triggered on "After saving new content" for your node type
- Add condition, compare data and compare the selector [site:current-page:path] is equals with your view path
- Add action page redirect to the view path

Can be useful too [Form Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/formblock) and Advanced Form Block modules, but putting php code in view headers you prevent to install extra module

And is done !